# Amnesia doesn't start due to audio problems

Tags: games, alsa

I have a problem with amnesia game. After Intro and clicking continue button few times, when game is supposed to start it crashes. Here is console output:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

I should mention I have integrated both graphic and sound card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem (Ubuntu 12.04, Ati 6450, gallium drivers).
The game is working now, after install this library:

`sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0`

Comment: Cheers. It helped with this error. Now I'got some other:P *** glibc detected *** ./Amnesia.bin64: corrupted double-linked list: 0x000000000b117f40 ***

Answer (score 0):

Try using the additional drivers tool in system setting to search for proprietary drivers you might be able to install. Installing ATI graphics cards(ATI Catalyst) drivers and rebooting helped in my situation.

Comment: this assumes the OP has an ATI/AMD graphics card.

Comment: @RobertArkenin you are correct. Another user (I've lost their name so sorry for not crediting whomever you are) also suggested a useful edit so I've updated my answer based on both pieces of feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Deinstalling pulseaudio did the trick for me. But keep in mind that the sound-mixer widget might vanish. You probably should install a ALSA-based-mixer after removing pulseaudio.